# Testing Android inapp subscription: You already own this subscription

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-checkout, subscription

I am testing Android  inapp subscription with a test account, after I entered a real credit card to buy, the subscription is ok, but I cannot find the token in the json response.

So in the developer console, I cancelled the order, when I try to re-subscribe again, it now show me the alert "You already own this subscription".

When I click the "Detail" in the box, it opened the Play Store app, but showing "Item not found"

Anyone experienced this error before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you might have solved the problem but take a look at this question [Subscription sample missing JSON parsing of purchaseToken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12002788/1075066) it this might be the case for JSON.

The reason you cannot re-subscribe i think is because you are already subscribed for that period. Your subscription will end when the billing cycle ends.

Answer (score 1):

Howard, the reason is that a subscription is active even after you cancel until the subscription period. It will continue to say that until the original subscription expires. I know, the Android implementation of subscriptions is really really kluegy. I've implemented in-app subs successfully on Android and have a lot of similar issues and one of them was you cannot re-purchase after cancelling if the item hasn't expired from it's original purchase date.