# Subscription sample missing JSON parsing of purchaseToken

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I have been recently studying code for In-App-Billing v2. And have found some issues with it.
I have earlier implemented In-App-Billing but wish to upgrade to subscription. On my research I found that  [Purchase token](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#token)  is recieved along with the JSON(Signed data) on successful purchase for subscription.

The demo's **Security.java** on successful verification of signature parses Json however the parsing of element Purchase-token is missing here.

```
            JSONObject jElement = jTransactionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int response = jElement.getInt("purchaseState");
            PurchaseState purchaseState = PurchaseState.valueOf(response);
            String productId = jElement.getString("productId");
            String packageName = jElement.getString("packageName");
            long purchaseTime = jElement.getLong("purchaseTime");
            String orderId = jElement.optString("orderId", "");
            String notifyId = null;
//          purchaseToken part that I have added
            String purchaseToken = jElement.optString("purchaseToken", "");
```

I haven't yet run the code since subscription doesn't have test product-ids and requires actual purchase.What I want to know is this token be parsed here or is the sample code provided has this part correctly implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vincent, that is correct. You have to modify Security.java as well as BillingService.java and ResponseHandler.java if you need the purhcaseToken to be validated.

Here it is:

Security.java:

```
public PurchaseState    purchaseState;
public String           notificationId;
public String           productId;
public String           orderId;
public long             purchaseTime;
public String           developerPayload;
public String           purchaseToken;
public String           packageName;

public VerifiedPurchase(PurchaseState purchaseState, String notificationId, String productId, String orderId, long purchaseTime,
        String developerPayload, String purchaseToken, String packageName) {
    this.purchaseState = purchaseState;
    this.notificationId = notificationId;
    this.productId = productId;
    this.orderId = orderId;
    this.purchaseTime = purchaseTime;
    this.developerPayload = developerPayload;
    this.purchaseToken = purchaseToken;
    this.packageName = packageName;
    }
}
```

Now in VerifyPurchase:

```
String developerPayload = jElement.optString("developerPayload", null);
// VK: Changes to parse the purchaseToken
String purchaseToken = jElement.optString("purchaseToken", null);
```

BillingService.java:

In purchaseStateChanged, modify:

```
ResponseHandler.purchaseResponse(this, vp.purchaseState, vp.productId, vp.orderId, vp.purchaseTime, vp.developerPayload, vp.purchaseToken, vp.packageName);
```

ResponseHandler.java:

Finally, change the definition of purchaseResponse to:

```
public static void purchaseResponse(final Context context, final PurchaseState purchaseState, final String productId, final String orderId, final long purchaseTime, final String developerPayload, final String purchaseToken,final String packageName)
```

Here you can make your app related logic changes as you here will have the purchaseToken.

If everything works, please accept!

Comment: Thanks But my security.java is on server side ...you could hae edited your answer...